# Get data from multiple models for rendering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I want to display all resources on a page, I might do:

```
Resource.find({}).exec(function (err, resources) {                          
    res.render("view", {                                                   
        resources: resources
```

However, what if I want to display all resources *and* all projects on the page simultaneously?  I could do:

```
Resource.find({}).exec(function (err, resources) {
    Projects.find({}).exec(function (err, projects) {
        res.render("view", {
            resources: resources,
            projects: projects
```

I think that there *has* to be a better/more correct way to do this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var async = require('async');
var resourcesQuery = Resource.find({});
var projectsQuery = Projects.find({});
var resources = {
  resources: resourcesQuery.exec.bind(resourcesQuery),
  projects: projectsQuery.exec.bind(projectsQuery)
};
async.parallel(resources, function (error, results) {
  if (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
    return;
  }
  res.render("view", results);
});
```

This will make the queries in parallel instead of serial, which will probably be faster.